# I can't find what's wrong with my backup script in VBS

Tags: vbscript

My script may be simplistically complex, but I am not seeing anything wrong with the code. For whatever reason, I can get every folder to copy instead of my Documents folder. My script says that the path is not found. When I tweak the code and Documents "path is found", I then get a "permissions denied" error. This problem has only been with the Documents folder. My code is below, I'm looking for help on how to resolve this one.

```
Option Explicit

Dim oShell, oFSO
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const Overwrite = True

Dim strHomeFolder
Dim usersName
Dim UserProfile
strHomeFolder = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")
usersName = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")

Sub DataBackup
    UserProfile = strHomeFolder & "\"

    Dim Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Favorites, Pictures, Videos, Music,
    Dim nDocuments, n1Documents

    Documents = UserProfile & "Documents"
    'nDocuments = "C:\Users\" + usersName + "\" + "Documents"+ "\" - " Test"
    'n1Documents = "C:\Users\user.profile.name\Documents\"           - "Test"

    Desktop = UserProfile & "\Desktop"
    Downloads = UserProfile & "\Downloads"
    Favorites = UserProfile & "\Favorites"
    Pictures = UserProfile & "\Pictures"
    Videos = UserProfile & "\Videos"
    Music = UserProfile & "\Music"

    Dim dtmValue, strDate, strTime
    dtmValue = Now()

    'Assuming that you are creating these folders in C:\
    strDate = "C:\MyBackup" & "_" & Month(dtmValue) & "-" & Day(dtmValue) & "-" & Year(dtmValue)
    strTime = strDate & "_" & Hour(dtmValue) & "." & Minute(dtmValue)

    Dim DestTimeStampFolder
    DestTimeStampFolder = StrTime

    oFSO.CreateFolder DestTimeStampFolder
    MsgBox "check if folder exists!"

    If Not oFSO.FolderExists(DestTimeStampFolder) Then
        Set DestTimeStampFolder = oFSO.CreateFolder(DestTimeStampFolder)
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    MsgBox DestTimeStampFolder & "\Documents"

    oFSO.CopyFolder Documents, DestTimeStampFolder & "\Documents", Overwrite
    'oFSO.CopyFolder nDocuments, DestTimeStampFolder & "\Documents", Overwrite  - ' "Used for Testing"
    'oFSO.CopyFolder n1Documents, DestTimeStampFolder & "\Documents", Overwrite - ' "Used for Testing"

    If Err Then
        WScript.Echo "Error # " & Err.Number
        WScript.Echo Err.Description
        WScript.Quit 1
    End If
End Sub
```

My debug code gives me an error code 70 (path not found) & 76 (permissions denied).

Comment: What about `Documents=UserProfile & "\Documents"` with the backslash to match your other folders?

Comment: That's a good eye... Now that it has found the Documents folder... I'm receiving a permissions denied when copying files... Would there be anything in the code making this happen?

Comment: Does the folder get created? If not, it seems unlikely you would get a permissions error trying to copy your own documents folder (unless there is a file in Documents that is currently in use). Perhaps try copying manually and see if you run into the same error.

Comment: In addition, If I were to manually copy the files over, it is not a problem.

Comment: I see that I answered part of your question already. To add, the folder does get created during the copy. I just tested the manual copy and no error was given